Preventing Image Distortion in Glide when Displaying Images
I'm encountering an issue while trying to display an image URL using the Glide library. When the aspect ratio of the image is very low, I'm observing distortion in the displayed image. This issue seems to occur with Glide, Picasso, and some other third-party libraries as well. Is there any way to prevent this distortion?
Here's the code snippet I'm currently using with Glide:
Glide.with(this)
   .load(GeneralData.getUserProfileImage()) //this is my image url
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
   .fitCenter()
    .into(profileImage)

